# Mysql root auth_socket to empty password

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, ubuntu-20.04

By default, `root` user in a freshly installed mysql-server is set to **auth_socket** which allows you to login via `sudo mysql`.

But in most cases, especially in your local machine, your application will connect to your database using a `root` credential with no or **empty string** password.

I followed this [post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04) step-by-step, however, I ended up having a non-empty password for my `root` user.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I did:

1. `sudo mysql`
2. `UNINSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';` in case you run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` during the installation. This will allow you to set an empty string to any user's password.
3. `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';`
4. `exit` mysql and restart the service --> `sudo service mysql restart`
5. You should be able to login using your root by `mysql -u root -p` and just hit ENTER if after being asked for the password.